# Avoid repeated values in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am working on employee table where an employee login and logout in a day. and these login and logouts are captures with some codes say 'I' and 'O'. And in our database, an employee may login more than once before logout and vice versa. 
a sample data looks like this. I have maintained some space in the sample data for some understanding of the data.

### Sample Data:

empid    terminal   prd      cdts                unique_id                         logflag
10025   system1     C    20140129025854CS   66D47E9841E1C149947A8D28B32BFF98        I
10025   system1     C    20140129031601CS   85268C4FF5523D4882DE492CC0716F79        O
10025   system1     C    20140129031849CS   501F181C0138C041B25F4BAFFC4FE9B4        I
10025   system1     C    20140129035014CS   209CF069D0A3A2428715018DAB6EC431        I

10025   system2     C    20140129035214CS   1248A63B50B1C244A8F21D9FD337F839        I
10025   system2     C    20140129040748CS   9A15F65724F0C04B93B42252BB3C50E3        O
10025   system2     C    20140129041636CS   41FB8A9D48B5C4489A4BC95F343613CC        O

10025   system2     D    20140129044217CS   917054DE757CAC40A97A3E714BEA9CD1        I
10025   system2     D    20140129035214CS   1248A63B50B1C244A8F21D9FD337F839        O
10025   system2     D    20140129040748CS   9A15F65724F0C04B93B42252BB3C50E3        O
10025   system2     D    20140129041636CS   41FB8A9D48B5C4489A4BC95F343613CC        I

### 10025   system2     D    20140129044217CS   917054DE757CAC40A97A3E714BEA9CD1        O

### Expected outcome:

empid    terminal   prd      cdts                unique_id                         logflag
10025   system1     C    20140129025854CS   66D47E9841E1C149947A8D28B32BFF98        I
10025   system1     C    20140129031601CS   85268C4FF5523D4882DE492CC0716F79        O
10025   system1     C    20140129031849CS   501F181C0138C041B25F4BAFFC4FE9B4        I

10025   system2     C    20140129035214CS   1248A63B50B1C244A8F21D9FD337F839        I
10025   system2     C    20140129040748CS   9A15F65724F0C04B93B42252BB3C50E3        O

10025   system2     D    20140129044217CS   917054DE757CAC40A97A3E714BEA9CD1        I
10025   system2     D    20140129035214CS   1248A63B50B1C244A8F21D9FD337F839        O
10025   system2     D    20140129041636CS   41FB8A9D48B5C4489A4BC95F343613CC        I
10025   system2     D    20140129044217CS   917054DE757CAC40A97A3E714BEA9CD1        O
like wise i have millions of records. my task is for each employee i should capture the first login and first logout in a sequence. for the above example i should get 4 records as result set mentioning his login and logouts.

Here first 3 columns (empid, terminal,prd ) need to participate in partitions. In words an **employee** enters into a **terminal** and uses different **prd**. so I want to capture the first Login and fist logout of **every employee** into **every system** and using **every prd**.

how can I achieve this. I am completely blocked. please help

Comment: "our database, an employee may login more than once before logout " really? That sounds broken

Comment: yes it sounds weird but it happens very often. some times even we login 2 times by mistake or to confirm if we doubt that we dint swipe correctly in our first attempt.

Comment: Please post your attempts and the issues with your code. Questions like "how to do this" without showing any effort are not usually welcome here.

Comment: Which version of the database?

Comment: Hey first of all thank you so much for your fastest reply. I am working on it right now. will post my feed back once i am done with that. I am using Oracle 12c

Comment: Actually to simplify the question i have mentioned only few columns here. But in reality there are other dependent columns to be included which i am trying to do now. And unable to get the desired results. Will you please look into the original table? shall I post the complete column list? @Aleksej

Comment: In [mcve] you find something useful on how to build an example that could really improve the question and help you to get good answers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cdts,
       empid,
       logflag,
       unique_id
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY empid, logflag, group_id ORDER BY cdts ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY cdts )
             - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY empid, logflag ORDER BY cdts )
             AS group_id
    FROM   your_table t
  ) t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/ZCUHV13670)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (select t.*, 
               lag(logflag) over (partition by empid order by cdts)  llf
          from t)
  where llf is null or llf <> logflag
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your direction. Finally I could able to get desired results with this query.

```
select CDTS,empid,cterm,prd,logflag,unique_id,FLAG from 
(
  select CDTS,empid,cterm,prd,logflag,unique_id, case when logflag = prev_logflag then 1 else 0 end as flag from
  (
   select CDTS,empid,cterm,prd,logflag,unique_id,lag(logflag) over(partition by empid,cterm order by prd,cdts) as prev_logflag from emp 
  )T 
)T1 where flag =0
```